# Sending websocket request from webpage to simple java server

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, java-websocket

I have this following javascript in my html file and i am trying to get the websocket working in the html file.

```
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>/home/bgautam/Documents/019.dcm.tar.xz</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success upload">Upload</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And the following script file

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".upload").click(function () {

        //geting the name of the file from the url
        var fileName=$(this).closest('td').prev().text();
        var abcd=fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        alert(abcd);
        //checking whether corresponding file is available in decompressed mode
        $.ajax({
            url:'/fileExistChecker?location='+fileName,
            type : 'POST',
            success:function (e) {
               if(e=='exist'){
                   var connection= new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5557');
                   connection.onopen=function () {
                       console.log("Connected...");
                       connection.send(abcd);
                       console.log("Data sent....")
                   };
                   connection.onmessage=function (p1) {
                       console.log(p1);
                   };
                   connection.onerror=function (event) {
                     connection.send(abcd);
                   };
                   connection.onclose=function (p1) {
                     console.log('connection closed');
                   };

               }
            },
            error:function (e) {
                alert(e);
            }



        });
    });
});
```

Now i made a java server with following code

```
public class ServerCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //running server in specific port number
        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5557);
            //server is ready for connecting to client
            System.out.println("Server is ready to connect to client");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected..... 200 OK");
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                String data = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next();

                Matcher get = Pattern.compile("^GET").matcher(data);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

                try {
                    if (get.find()) {
                        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
                        match.find();
                        byte[] response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                                + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                                + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                                + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                                + DatatypeConverter
                                .printBase64Binary(
                                        MessageDigest
                                                .getInstance("SHA-1")
                                                .digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
                                                        .getBytes("UTF-8")))
                                + "\r\n\r\n")
                                .getBytes("UTF-8");

                        out.write(response, 0, response.length);
                    } else {
                        out.write("this is sending".getBytes());

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                System.out.println("i ma here");
                //reading message from the client
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;
                    byte[] b;
                    String clientMessage = null;
                   /* while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);

                    }*/

                    b=bufferedReader.readLine().getBytes("UTF-8");
                    System.out.println("i am here");
                    System.out.println(clientMessage=new String(b));

                //sending messsage to client
                OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);
                printWriter.write("Server :" + new Date() + "\n " + clientMessage);
                printWriter.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                    System.out.println("i am here");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                System.out.println("i ma hre ");

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }}
```

I have done handshake as you have seen in the code but mostly it is unstable and always give me some output that seems like encrypted. How can i make this work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: it looks like you open a websocket connection upon an event. Aren't you supposed to have the connection opened first and then process the event ?